# Is it possible to load data generated by .py script hosted on Google Dataproc to local database?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I`m curently working on recommender system and trying to find optimal design solution for this problem. I want to deploy my python script with recommender engine to Spark cluster provided by Google Dataproc.

Is it possible to load results(recommendations) to the local database directly after computing(without using Google Cloud as medium)?

Comment: Where's your local database running?

Comment: It runs locally on my machine.